# Creating stripe subscription (Mern stack), if there any security issue using res.json instead of res.redirect

Tags: reactjs, node.js, express, stripe-payments

I have followed the docs from stripe: [Prebuilt subscription page with Stripe Checkout | Stripe Documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/quickstart).

I would like to change the code a bit and use fetch in react, and res.json(session.url) in nodejs endpoint.

I wonder if the following code has security issue? Because I redirect to session.url in React manually instead of using res.redirect(session.url) in express.js server.

```js
// React
const ProductDisplay = () => {
    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        try {
            const response = await fetch('http://localhost:4242/create-checkout-session', {
                method: "POST",
            });
            const url = await response.json();
            window.location.href = url;

        } catch (err) {
            console.log('err:', err)
        }
    }

    return (
        <section>
            <div className="product">
                <Logo />
                <div className="description">
                    <h3>Starter plan</h3>
                    <h5>$20.00 / month</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
            <form
            // onSubmit={handleSubmit}
            >
                <button id="checkout-and-portal-button" type="submit"
                    onClick={handleSubmit}
                >
                    Checkout
                </button>
            </form>
        </section>
    );
}
```

```js
// expressjs server 
app.post('/create-checkout-session', async (req, res) => {
  const prices = await stripe.prices.list({
    lookup_keys: [],
    expand: ['data.product'],
  });

  const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    billing_address_collection: 'auto',
    line_items: [
      {
        price: prices.data[0].id,
        quantity: 1,
      },
    ],
    mode: 'subscription',
    success_url: `http://localhost:3000/`,
    cancel_url: `${YOUR_DOMAIN}?canceled=true`,

  });
  // return res.redirect(303,session.url);
  return res.status(200).json(session.url)

});
```

Comment: What's your security concern? The above code looks like it is just creating session server-side and then doing a client-side redirect to that session's url.

Comment: @codename_duchess, does this piece of code create vulnerability for hacker to attack? Such as xss, csrf or ddos or other attack?